# how to Put an json array in AWS dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can we insert the following data to aws dynamodb tale.

```
{
  "userId":"4",
  "gpId": "44",
  "uname": "username",
  "position":"Cloud Solution Engineer",
  "companyName" : "xyz Technlologies",
  "skills": [{"linux":"1","windows":"2","Docker": "3"}]
}
```

I have tried using the following code in node.js

```
    var userId=event.userId;
    var gpId=event.gpId;
    var fbId=event.fbId;
    var uname=event.uname;
    var position=event.position;
    var role=event.role;
    var companyName=event.companyName;
    var skills=event.skills;

dynamodb.putItem({
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Item" : {
            "userId": {"N": userId},
            "gpId": {"N": gpId},
            "uname" : {"S":uname},
            "position" : {"S":position},
            "role" : {"S":role},
            "companyName" : {"S":companyName},
            "skills" : {"SS":skills}
        }
```

I am trying the below code it is giving below error to me.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Expected params.Item['skills'].S to be a string",
  "errorType": "InvalidParameterType",
  "stackTrace": [
    "ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)",
    "ParamValidator.validateType (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:218:10)",
    "ParamValidator.validateString (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:150:14)",
    "ParamValidator.validateScalar (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:130:21)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:94:21)",
    "ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMap (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:117:14)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:92:21)",
    "ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)"
  ]
}
```

I tried to change `{"S": skills}` with `skills`.

it is giving me following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected key '0' found in params.Item['skills']",
  "errorType": "UnexpectedParameter",
  "stackTrace": [
    "ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)",
    "ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMap (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:117:14)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:92:21)",
    "ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)",
    "ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)",
    "ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)",
    "Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:109:42)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)"
  ]
}
```

I have tried applying map as suggested in an answer but it gives me the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "There were 3 validation errors:\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'linux' found in params.Item['skills'].M['0']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'windows' found in params.Item['skills'].M['0']\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Docker' found in params.Item['skills'].M['0']",
  "errorType": "MultipleValidationErrors",
  "stackTrace": [
    "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'linux' found in params.Item['skills'].M['0']",
    "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'windows' found in params.Item['skills'].M['0']",
    "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Docker' found in params.Item['skills'].M['0']",
    "ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:40:28)",
    "Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:109:42)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
    "callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)",
    "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:75:9",
    "finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:308:7)",
    "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:324:9",
    "EnvironmentCredentials.get (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:126:7)",
    "getAsyncCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:318:24)",
    "Config.getCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:338:9)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-data-types, check this

Answer (score 0):

`skills` is not a string set (**SS**), it should have a Map attribute type (**M**) after the following 0-index assignment:

```
var skills = event.skills[0];
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html